# windows service not starting on a certain computer

Tags: c#, windows-services

I've written a windows service in C# which basically reads a text file periodically, and inserts its content to SQL Server database.
i've installed this service to over 100 computers in the company and all is working fine except one.
but when i go to services screen and restart it, it starts working.

based on similar topics in stackoverflow, here is what i did so far:

1- uninstalled the service and installed again.

2- in the properties section of windows service, set it to start automatically (delayed), and restart if failed.

3- did debugging in my computer again and it worked fine, but i don't have any chance to debug in said computer.

4- the service sends and e-mail to me if there is an error but it sends none, so i am assuming that it's not even starting.

What should i do to trace where the error is? is there any place where the windows service error logs are stored?

Comment: It might be crashing somewhere. Check event viewer logs for that. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Yes, i examined the event logs and this is the keyword for "Service stopped" log: 0x8080000000000000. I googled it and found out that there was a hotfix for that, but it did not work neither.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to amend your code if you haven't already done so......In the class that inherits from ServiceBase you can set AutoLog to true this will write to the event log which may help. I'd suggest placing this in the services constructor and reinstalling, if you have some kind of config file perhaps you could modify your code so that you have the option of turning logging on or off.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i think autolog property was true by default. i will check event viewer as Abhineet suggested and see if there is a log, if not i will set it to true and try again.